# how can I use updatepanel for more than 1 control

Tags: asp.net

```
<div class="step-content">
  <div class="step-pane active" id="step1">
     <div class="control-group ">
       <label class="control-label" for="inputWarning">Please select the Event Name</label>
       <div class="controls">
       <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="EventName" DataValueField="EventId"></asp:DropDownList>
       <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:WBENCConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [EventId], [EventName] FROM [Event]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="step-pane" id="step2">
 <div class="control-group " >
    <asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <div class="controls">
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
              <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
         </ContentTemplate>
         <Triggers>
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RadioButtonList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
         </Triggers>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="step-pane" id="step3">
  <div class="control-group ">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputWarning">
       <span class="muted">You can learn more about the program <a href="#">here</a></span></label>
         <div class="controls">
              <label class="radio">
                 <asp:RadioButton ID="Radio1" runat="server" Text="Yes" value="option1" /></label>
                 <label class="radio">
              <asp:RadioButton ID="Radio2" runat="server" Text="No" value="option2" /></label>
                  <label class="radio">
              <asp:RadioButton ID="Radio3" runat="server" Text="Uncertain" value="option2" /></label>
           </div>
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step-pane" id="step4">
     <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="selectError30">Which days will you be available to participate in the Matchmaker Sessions?</label>
           <div class="controls">
              <asp:DropDownList ID="selectError30" runat="server" OnDataBound="selectError30_DataBound">
               </asp:DropDownList>
             </div>
       </div>
       <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Upload your capability statement. <a style="color: #67c2ef;" href="#">What's this?</a></label>
          <div class="controls">
              <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

here the DropDownlist1_onselectedIndexChanged event got full page load..

and RadioButtonList1 event also get page load...

here how can I use the Update Panel to overcome the full page load....

In my code all events perform Page_Load....

I want to prevent that loading....

Answer (score 0):

If there is a full page load then since panel is inside the page, it will also get refreshed. You can put the drop down inside another update panel. This will prevent the refreshing of radio button update panel.

Comment: Depends upon your purpose. If your purpose is to keep every control separate and unaffected. You can. Otherwise you can try to group controls logically. And also, you can group controls based on the update behavior. i.e if you want ctrl1 .. ctrl5 to be in related and if one updates then other should also, then go ahead place them in one update panel. Otherwise if you want ctrl1 & ctrl2 to be unaffected from updates on ctrl3..ctrl5 then you can place the controls in two different update panels.